# Updating Chartjs to 2.5 with custom code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chart.js

I am using this custom code to render negative barchart values:

**html**

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
```

**js**

```
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, -30]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90, -42]
        }
    ]
};

var options = {
    scaleBeginAtZero: false,
    responsive: true,
    scaleStartValue : -50 
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
```

(found on this codepen  http://codepen.io/ranstyr/pen/yepved)
However...that code is in Chartjs version 1.0.2  and I need to use 2.5

Here is my codepen of the potential update to 2.5, but I'm not getting it to work. 
http://codepen.io/nothingtoseehere/pen/oBOqJw

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of what you're looking for...

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWgeqx

In my experience you'll need a div with a height and width defined to wrap the canvas. I believe you get the responsive for free. Code below.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                hoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, -30]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                borderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                hoverBorderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                borderWidth: 5,
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90, -42]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    min: -50
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a link to the Chart.js documentation. The Bar and Scales sections will be helpful. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Comment: That's great...but why is it in black & white?  The rbg values are in color.

Comment: Fixed above. Had to update the field names, also increased the thickness for visibility. Check out the codepen now.